# Can't select more than two columns in Prepared Statement Query without page break

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm learning prepared statements to make my website more secure. At the moment I can't select more than two columns in my query without my page breaking. Since I'm new to this, and I can't find anything online regarding this, can someone please give me advice?

Here's my code:

```
/* creating query */
$sql_r = "SELECT rate, title, review FROM rating WHERE owner = ?";

/* Preparing query */
if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql_r)){

    /* binding parameters */
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

    /* Executing the query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($rate, $title, $review);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();
}
```

The code above doesn't work, but if I was to remove the `review` column from the query, it would, and the variables would display as they should on my page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check for errors then `mysqli_error($db)`

Comment: Or [`mysqli_stmt_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php) - since you're using prepared statements

Comment: also, if the amount of columns in the select doesn't match with the binded results or vice-versa or the number of placeholders, that could also cause it. Your question is unclear; you need to tell us/show us what you did that caused your code to fail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Fred-ii-! I'm currently trying to do the mysqli_error($db). It's a bit difficult to echo it out since the page is completely white and doesn't show anything. EDIT: The only thing I did to cause the code to fail was switching from a mysqli query (without prepared statements) to a query WITH prepared statements.

Comment: there isn't much else I can add to my 2nd comment; we need to know what you did and what syntax was used that caused the error.

Comment: My goal is to select data from a query to display on a profile. I'm using PS to make it more secure. That's all, really. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Thanks for your help @Fred-ii-. I played with it some more, and it looks like the PS doesn't like the `review` column with is LONGTEXT. That seems to be the only problem. I'll play with it some more to fix the issue. Thanks for your advice!